# AWS CloudFormation UserData

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to transfer $var to UserData for invoke script inside EC2 instance.

My example code:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Resources:
  ASLaunchConfig:
    Type: 'AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration'
    Properties:
      AssociatePublicIpAddress: false
      ImageId: ami-0bxxxxxxxxccb
      InstanceType: 't2.medium'
      KeyName: 'keyname'
      LaunchConfigurationName: 'LaunchConfig'
      UserData: !Base64 | 
            #!/bin/bash
            blabla-${ClusterName}
            somecode
            somecode
Parameters:
  ClusterName:
    Description: Cluster Name
    Type: String
    Default: cluster-dev
    AllowedValues:
      - cluster-dev
      - cluster-qa
```

But after built "Launch Config" thru CloudFormation I received in EC2 UserData
strings like:

```
#!/bin/bash
blabla-${ClusterName}
somecode
somecode
```

I'm expecting something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
blabla-cluster-dev
somecode
somecode
```

I checked a lot of topics, but I'm still can't found decision.

Answer (score 1):

You missed the `!Sub` which would replace the variable. Try this:

```
UserData:
  Fn::Base64:
    !Sub |
      # rest of it
```

The [key point](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-base64.html) is this:

> If you use the short form and immediately include another function ..., use the full function name for at least one of the functions.

Examples:

```
!Base64
  "Fn::Sub": string

Fn::Base64:
  !Sub string
```